# Checkbox Checked status change depends on five other checkboxs

Tags: c#, if-statement, logical-operators

I have totally 6 checkbox's. I want to check or uncheck 6th check box based on the status of remaining 5 checkboxes. 
If any of the two check boxes or more is checked true then 6th one should be true if not then false. 
I have tried different if statements but not successful.
so far the best i found is this logic

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true || checkBox3.Checked == true || checkBox4.Checked == true || checkBox5.Checked == true)
            {
                checkBox6.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox6.Checked = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if ((checkBox2.Checked == true || checkBox3.Checked == true) || (checkBox4.Checked == true || checkBox5.Checked == true))
            {
                checkBox6.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox6.Checked = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

This logic is not working when i have only 1 checkbox checked true. in that condition the 6th one should be false but not.
Any suggestions?? 
I have this code for all checkboxs under checked event.

Comment: You probably have used || when you should have &&.  Try changing this and see what happens.

Comment: This is only working off checkbox1's CheckChanged event, so unless you've got the same code in all of the other checkboxes CheckChanged event it will only work off the first checkbox.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I tried but not succesful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a separate method that each of your checkboxes CheckChange events can call:

```
private void SetCheckBox6()
{
    var checkboxStatuses = new List<bool>
    {
        checkbox1.Checked,
        checkbox2.Checked,
        checkbox3.Checked,
        checkbox4.Checked,
        checkbox5.Checked
    }

    checkbox6.Checked = false;

    if(checkboxStatuses.Where(x => x == true).Count() > 1)
    {
        checkbox6.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Other logic that needs to happen on check changed...

    SetCheckBox6();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lays in the if statement on line 16 because if checkBox1 is not checked and one of the other checkboxes is checked it will automatically enable checkBox6 to be checked. Because you are basically checking if any of the other 4 checkboxes are checked and if one is without checkBox1 to be check it will go to line 16 and pass the if statement because you are using the || operators, consider using the && operators and see how they work.

[C# operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

Another way of going on this is to check the Controls in the form if they are a CheckBox and count the amount of checkboxes checked and making sure it is not an instance of checkBox6 this way you could use endless checkBoxes and have just a small function that checks all of them

```
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (CheckBox item in this.Controls) // Loop all checkboxes in form
            {
                if (item.CheckState == CheckState.Checked && item != checkBox6) // Check if checkbox is checked and not instance of checkBox6
                {
                    i++; // Increment amount of checkBoxes checked
                }

            }
            checkBox6.Checked = i >= 2 ? true : false; // enable checkBox6 if more than 2 checkboxes are checked
        }
```

Don't forget to add the CheckChanged Event "checkBox1_CheckedChanged" to all other checkboxes

Comment: It wouldn't be a good idea to add that event to all other checkboxes in case there was other logic required for the other checkboxes.

Comment: @sr28 well, the question was that he has a total of 6 checkboxes, it is correct that this would intervene with other logic in case there are other checkboxes but it was just another solution for the question :) and you can always add the checkBoxes that don't need to be checked to the "if" statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:
Add `CheckedChanged` event of 1-5 checkboxs to this method.

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       int count = 0;
       if (checkBox1.Checked)
        count++;
       if (checkBox2.Checked)
        count++;
       if (checkBox3.Checked)
        count++;
       if (checkBox4.Checked)
        count++;
       if (checkBox5.Checked)
        count++;
       checkBox6.Checked = count >= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try *Linq* to query a *collection* (say, array) of `CheckBox`es

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  checkBox6.Checked = new bool[] {
    checkBox1.Checked, 
    checkBox2.Checked, 
    checkBox3.Checked, 
    checkBox4.Checked, 
    checkBox5.Checked}.Count(c => c) >= 2;
}
```

Do not forget to assign **all** `checkBox1`..`checkBox5` `CheckedChanged` event handlers to `checkBox1_CheckedChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logic try this

```
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox6.Checked = false;
        if (checkBox1.Checked && (checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked || checkBox4.Checked || checkBox5.Checked))
        {
            checkBox6.Checked = true;
        }
        else if ((checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked) || (checkBox4.Checked && checkBox5.Checked))
        {
            checkBox6.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```